# Add github public repository on odoo app store

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

I have my public repository on git-hub, and i want to add this repository on Odoo app store, There is any way to do this .??

I search on Google but didn't found any way to do this.

There are some article which are shown that the repository should be private.
If anyone has any solution please shared..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your repository does not have to be private in order to submit it to the Odoo App store, however it would make sense to use a private repository for proprietary (paid) addons.

To upload your app or theme to the Odoo app store you need to register/login on [Odoo.com](https://www.odoo.com/) and go to the [App Upload](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/upload) page. There you need to specify the URL of your Git repository in the following format:

```
git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git#<branch>
```

Please ensure that:

> - There is one folder per App/Theme at the root of the repository.
> - You specify the branch name of your Git repository by adding `#branch_name` at the end of the repo URL.
> - The branch name exactly matches the series name for which your modules are meant, so `#8.0` for version 8.0.

Once you add the repository you can scan it for Odoo addons/themes.

If your repository is private (eg. for proprietary addons), there is a section on that in the [FAQ](https://www.odoo.com/apps/faq#heading_maintainer_faq_06):

> To publish your modules on our platform, we need to be allowed to read
>   from your repository. If you are on [Github](https://github.com/), you can simply authorize
>   our [online-odoo](https://github.com/online-odoo) user on your repository. If you are on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), you
>   can authorize our [OdooApps](https://bitbucket.org/OdooApps/) user. If you use another service, you will
>   need to authorize our [public SSH key](https://github.com/online-odoo.keys) instead. Don't forget to use the
>   SSH url of your repository when registering it to allow us to identify
>   using ssh. For example for GitHub, it would be something like
>   `git@github.com:odoo/odoo#9.0`.

Comment: **Each module needs to be in a separate folder at the root of the repository, even if there is only one module.
If you have all the files of your module at the root of your repository, you need to create a new folder with the name of your module and move all the files in it.**

Comment: Hey @SagarT, the error means what it says - if you have just a single addon, you need to put it inside a directory, eg. `your_module_name`. Similarly, if you have multiple addons in the repository, each addon should have its own directory in the repository, however they can't be in a subdirectory - each addon directory should be at the top level of the repository.

Comment: Ok, Means I Have to upload my addons folder, not single module.

Comment: got it, Thank You @Naglis

Comment: Does creating multiple repository for each odoo version is also fine to submit? @Naglis